# C# Wrapper for C++ but compiles as static library only

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, wrapper

I am trying to run un-managed native C++ class code from C# by writing a wrapper. My C++ code compiles as a static library (.lib) with no problems. The code depends on other code which, I believe, are all compiled as static libraries. I am not able to compile this as a DLL as there are linker errors.

I have just learnt that the wrapper needs to be compiled as a DLL so that it may be invoked from C#. Is this true? Can I not compile my wrapper as a static library to be used in C#?

Comment: Sounds like you are refering to [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services). As far as I know this works with DLLs only. How about creating a Managed C++ DLL with your native C++ included? This would allow to directly add a reference within your C# project and access your Managed C++ classes.

Comment: I would take your suggestion to creating a managed C++ DLL. Do you have a good tutorial that explains how to convert un-managed to managed?

Comment: I've once created a Managed C++ DLL for Html Tidy. [Here is my Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17124/A-managed-wrapper-for-the-HTML-Tidy-library), maybe it is of some help to you.

Comment: Also, most of my dependencies are compiled as static libraries - to create a managed C++ DLL, do I need to re-compile dependencies as DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# cannot load .lib files.

P/Invoke can only load .DLL files (they don't have to be named .DLL but they have to be the right file format).